# error in sql query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have this query

```
DECLARE @Base nvarchar(200) 

SET @Base = 'WITH Base AS (SELECT Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id DESC) RN FROM'
                        + Quotename(@SampleWorkTbl) + ')
                        SELECT * INTO ##temp FROM Base'

EXEC (@Base)

SELECT * FROM   ##temp

declare @command nvarchar(max)

Set @command='SELECT TOP 15 [Name],[ImageAddress],(SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(Id) FROM' + QUOTENAME(@SampleWorkTbl) + ') as AllSampleCount FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@SampleWorkTbl) + 
            ' WHERE [Id] IN (SELECT TOP 15 Id From ##temp WHERE RN > ((@Count-1)*15) ORDER BY Id DESC) ORDER BY Id DESC'

exec (@command)

drop table ##temp
```

I want get `[Name],[ImageAddress]` and count of Id from any table name that pass to the procedure

but instead of `get name` , `image address` and `Id` I get this data

```
Id  RN
10   1
9    2
8    3
7    4
6    5
5    6
4    7
3    8
2    9
1    10
```

and when try again i get this error

```
There is already an object named '##temp' in the database.
```

@SampleWorkTbl is a name of any table that pass to the this query

how i can fix this problem ?

thank you for you help

Comment: what is @SampleWorkTbl ??

Comment: @SampleWorkTbl is a name of any table that pass to the this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

For

> There is already an object named '##temp' in the database.

Before Creating New Temp Table You need to Use This:

```
if  (object_ID('tempdb..##temp')) is not NULL
DROP TABLE ##temp
```

You need to add `[Name],[ImageAddress],ID` these columns to get desire output

```
 SET @Base = 'WITH Base AS (SELECT [Name],[ImageAddress],ID,COUNT(ID) CntID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id DESC) RN FROM'
                        + Quotename(@SampleWorkTbl) + ' GROUP BY [Name],[ImageAddress],ID)
                        SELECT * INTO ##temp FROM Base'
```

Comment: thank for your hehow i can fix the problem of name and imageaddress and count of id?

Comment: @SH.Developer Updated now

Answer (score 1):

Your Query is executing until

```
EXEC (@Base)
```

You are getting the

> There is already an object named '##temp' in the database.

at

```
SELECT * FROM   ##temp
```

means you got error somewhere and it didn't reached the point

```
drop table ##temp
```

as @Ganesh_Devlekar mentioned
Try adding

```
if  (object_ID('tempdb..##temp')) is not NULL
DROP TABLE ##temp
```

at the Starting